# I want to record video on canvas in React

Tags: javascript, record

I did a long search and felt the need to ask here. The npm packages I used before did nothing. Has anyone done or experienced such an application before? All I want to do is record it as a video while drawing on the canvas element. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API), [captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) and [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) for that

Here's an example where some coloured squares are painted on a canvas, then a video is created with the recording:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const stream = canvas.captureStream();
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm' });
const video = document.querySelector('video');

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(200, 50, 50, 50);
}, 1000);

recorder.start();
setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 2000);
recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (evt) => {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(evt.data);
  video.src = url;
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<video controls></video>
```

But basically once you get to the point where you have the recording URL, you can do anything with it, including creating a download link, automatically downloading the recording, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However, I did not state what I wanted to do for react in the question. Sorry. My main problem is actually on the react side.

Comment: Yes but it's a pure JS solution so it works in React, where is the issue?

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I just haven't started react and I don't know exactly how to transfer it to react.  When I transfer it like this, I get a property null error in the video src part.  I also get an error like Cannot read property 'getContext' of null. So unfortunately it makes a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Well just use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead of `querySelector` and you're good. "How to transfer it to React" is hard to answer further if you don't explain your use case and include [an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ahh. Tank you i will look at refs parts.

Comment: Hello there. I managed to record video, but I want to also record audio. Do you have any knowledge about this topic?